# Show grayscale OpenCV image with matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I use opencv3 of python installed it by anaconda using:

`conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0`

But when i use it to convert a picture to grayscale, like:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

image = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png')

image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

print (image.shape)
print (image1.shape)

plt.imshow(image1)
```

[image]
I donnot know why:

I use windows + miniconda.
Can anyone know why and help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what you mean, I just use. `image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)`

Comment: what does cv2.imshow() instead of plt.imshow() give you ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are supposed to add another parameter in `plt.imshow()` so as to mention that you want a gray scale image.

Modify the last line like this: `plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')`

Upon doing so I got the following:

[image]

Comment: @KerwinXiao Yu can also try displaying using `cv2.imshow()`