# how to store grayscale image in a variable, not just to plot the image but also to use the image for other purposes?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I tried to read the given image in grayscale format but the image is being read in greenish form

```
img=cv2.imread(path,0)
fig,axs=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
axs.imshow(img)
axs.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

I have tried the following solutions but none of them is working
`img=cv.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` 
`img=cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

> > **Greenish image:**
> > [Greenish image generated instead of grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcXmD.png) 
> > **Original image:**
> > [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOPON.png)

and I have to use only plot don't ask me to use cv2.imshow please

Can anyone Help me resolve this issue?

I have tried the following solutions but none of them is working
`img=cv.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` 
`img=cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Answer (score -1):

[Here is your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228246/show-grayscale-opencv-image-with-matplotlib)

Modify line like this: `axs.imshow(img, cmap='gray')`

Comment: no i want to store the image into another variable not just plot it

Answer (score -1):

the following might just solve your problem:

```
fig,axs=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
arr = np.asarray(img)
plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
axs.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```